# Is there an Apple API to get app downloads data?

Tags: ios, analytics, app-store-connect-api

Apple now has a web dashboard that provides information on the number of installs, re-installs etc.

Does anyone know if there is an API available from Apple for this same (downloads) data ? I looked around their docs and could not see anything but hoping maybe there is and I missed it. Thanks!

[image]